# Google App Engine Authentication

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, authentication

I would like my application - an iPhone app, to use the Google App Engine to authenticate for all requests. I would prefer a single email/password to be stored inside the app, and to be used for these reqeusts.

Now, suppose the app is installed by say 1000 people and all 1000 people use it at the same time - will google cause issues saying that there are 1000 separate requests from separate ips coming for a same email username/password?

I am thinking of testing it with say - 4 or 5 machines. But it is difficult to properly test it - so if somebody knows it - I would be much obliged if you could let me know about the same.

Regards

K

Comment: Yeah--that probably won't work. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: We have an app and a web service used by that app. We would prefer if our app authenticates itself with the webservice. We were looking at specific authentication mechanisms for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? There's absolutely no point in using the Users API if you're going to hardcode a single set of credentials into every copy of the app - and it's very likely indeed that the account would be suspended.

Comment: We have an app and a web service used by that app. We would prefer if our app authenticates itself with the webservice. We were looking at specific authentication mechanisms for that.

Comment: Generate a random 'secret', and embed it in both the site and the app. Use it in the app to calculate HMACs for requests, and send them with the request. Verify them on the server.